# MongooseJS Odd Casting Error with Route Name in Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on a backend, and I have this route that is supposed to return just an array of ID's from the database for later lazy loading. My route is defined like this:

```
 router.get('/list', (req, res) => {
   Insider.find({}, {_id}).then(insiders => {
     if (!insiders) {
       res.status(400).json({ error: 'unable to find list of insiders' });
     }
     res.json(insiders);
   }).catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
 });
```

which should return an array like this `[_id, _id, _id....]`

But I am getting a very weird error:

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value "list" at path "_id" for model
>   "insiders"   CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "list" at
>   path "_id" for model "insiders"
>         at new CastError (C:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\ccs-express-mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:27:11)
>         at ObjectId.cast (C:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\ccs-express-mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:158:13)
>         at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\ccs-express-mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:724:12)
>         at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (C:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\ccs-express-mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1113:15)
>         at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (C:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\ccs-express-mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1103:15)
>         at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (C:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\ccs-express-mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1082:15)
>         at cast (C:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\ccs-express-mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:300:32)
>         at model.Query.Query.cast (C:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\ccs-express-mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3309:12)
>         at model.Query.Query._castConditions (C:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\ccs-express-mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1293:10)
>         at model.Query.Query._findOne (C:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\ccs-express-mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1518:8)
>         at process.nextTick (C:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\ccs-express-mongo\node_modules\kareem\index.js:333:33)
>         at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

I've confirmed that it is actually the route name that is leaking into my route handler. (i.e. I changed the route to `/jerry` for S&G, and "list" was replaced with "jerry" in the error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your **find** method try to change it to like this

```
 router.get('/list', (req, res) => {
 Insider.find({}, {id:0}).then(insiders => {
  if (!insiders) {
   res.status(400).json({ error: 'unable to find list of insiders' });
   }
     res.json(insiders);
  }).catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
});
```

I think you should use id instead of _id and set its value to 0

Comment: if you want just the id use my code and change 0 to 1 and try it , I think it will work

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this was a route priority issue. there was a `/:insiderId` route before the `/list` route.

apologies.